# Slim 3 Framework - Should I be using Route Groups for my API?

Tags: php, api, rest, slim

Should I be using this structure...

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$app = new \Slim\App;

$app->get('/books', 'getBooks');
$app->get('/books/{id}', 'getBook');

$app->run();

function getBooks() {
    // Return list of books
}

function getBook($id) {
    // Return a single book
}
```

Or this "Route Groups" one?

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$app = new \Slim\App;

$app->group('/books', function () use ($app) {
    $app->get('', function ($req, $res) {
        // Return list of books
    });

    $app->get('/{id:\d+}', function ($req, $res, $args) {
        // Return a single book
    });
});

$app->run();
```

What is the better way? The former seems much cleaner. I am relatively new, so I am unaware of the pros and cons.

Comment: actually, to me, the latter looks much more better structured. but if both work, you might want to do it just the way you like it better, SO isn't really suited for opinion questions

Comment: @nonchip That's the thing. I don't know whether it's down to opinion or there's a proper convention.

Comment: well then take a look at docs or example projects for the framework, and whatever seems to be used there more consistently could be the convention. as a rule of thumb i'd say the first example is fine (=easy) if you keep things short, but the second one seems better to manage (both from an optimizing router's and from a programmer's point of view), so use that if you're going to do lots of stuff with books.

Comment: also, the second version is passing around function references directly, while the first one has to look them up from strings (which is usually slower).

Comment: There really isn't a convention. Most of the core devs for Slim don't use routing groups at all in production.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Generally, you use route groups to organise similar resources or content so you can visibly see their relationship in the code. Route groups are also helpful if you need to put any special conditions such as middleware on a specific group. For example, You might have an administrator section on your website, and you want to make sure that the user is actually an administrator before accessing the controller.

```
$app->get('panel/admin', 'Admin/DashboardController:index')->add($adminAuth);
$app->get('panel/admin/users', 'Admin/UserController:index')->add($adminAuth);
$app->post('panel/admin/users', 'Admin/UserController:create')->add($adminAuth);
```

Obviously, it would make more sense to group these routes together because they share similar traits. If you ever need to change anything about these traits in the future (like the type of middleware), you would only have to do it once.

```
$app->group('/panel', function() use ($app) {
    $app->group('/admin', function() use ($app) {
        $app->get('', 'Admin/DashboardController:index');
        $app->get('/users', 'Admin/UserController:index');
        $app->post('/users', 'Admin/UserController:create');

    })->add($adminAuth);
})->add($userAuth);
```

It's also helpful if you would ever want to expand the use case of that specific URI, so lets say you want to roll out a new feature in the panel that regular users can use.

```
$app->group('/panel', function() use ($app) {

    $app->group('/admin', function() use ($app) {

        $app->get('', 'Admin/DashboardController:index');
        $app->get('/users', 'Admin/UserController:index');
        $app->post('/users', 'Admin/UserController:create');

    })->add($adminAuth);


    $app->get('', 'DashboardController:index');

})->add($userAuth);
```

Although it isn't a great deal of importance, it is just good practice to layout all your code as organised as possible, and route groups allow you to do this.

Comment: Note inside the group closure, `$this` is used instead of `$app`. Slim binds the closure to the application instance for you, just like it is the case with route callback binds with container instance.

inside group closure, `$this` is bound to the instance of Slim\App
inside route closure, `$this` is bound to the instance of Slim\Container

[Slim Documentation: Route Groups](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/router.html#route-groups)

Comment: @red true  but IDEs easily understands use($app) than $this. I go with the above method for all my apps instead of using $this.